# node.js Buffer data decode

Tags: node.js, buffer

I am getting data from TCP into node.js. The data is in buffer format and looks like:

```
♣ ? d       ?&+?
```

How can I parse that data into normal strings, eg 12345

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Node buffers have a toString method, here's the documentation on it http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/buffers.html#buffer.toString

Comment: The buffer is is an Open Sound Control format. Tying to decode with mybuffer.toString("utf8", start=44, 60) gives me >?V?◄►7?N?ND

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like this:

https://github.com/rmustacc/node-ctype

which provides accessors for reading and writing binary buffers.